# Spamming the tag wiki

Tags: discussion, moderation

Not sure if any of your have noticed a [certain user](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/5709/hossiman) trying to edit tag wikis with spam. I've rejected both of them, however I'm going to assume that more more may be submitted.

How are we to flag a user to a moderator if they've not posted any questions or answers? There's no option to do so on their profile, so Meta is the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. That user should no longer exist. If you want a simpler solution chat at me or another moderator with the user in the Joomla chat. That will send us a notice and we can review.

Comment: Ok thanks David ;)